# Initializing an array with identical elements: `==` operator says arrays are the same, but they behave differently. Why?

Tags: ruby, immutability

Here's my code:

```
a=["foo","foo","foo"]
b=["foo"]*3
a==b # => true

a.each{|i| i<<"bar"}
b.each{|i| i<<"bar"}
a==b # => false
```

I get what I expect for `a`:

```
["foobar", "foobar", "foobar"]
```

but for `b`, I get this:

```
["foobarbarbar", "foobarbarbar", "foobarbarbar"]
```

1. Why is this happening? Is it a bug?
2. Is there a way of filling an array with many identical strings that avoids this problem?

Comment: It is not Ruby's bug. It is **your** bug. Don't easily assume someone else's bug when you are a beginner. Probably it will take ten more years until you can file a Ruby's bug.

Comment: @sawa Hey.. if I *really* thought I'd found a bug I would have gone straight to  Ruby, not Stackoverflow :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's just that the lines

```
a=["foo","foo","foo"]
b=["foo"]*3
```

Are not the same.  The second is inserting the SAME OBJECT three times into the `b` array.  In the `a` array, you have three different objects.  In all cases, the objects are strings with the text "foo".

You can confirm this by examining the object ids.

```
a[0].object_id == a[1].object_id
=> false

b[0].object_id == b[1].object_id
=> true
```

So when you mutate the object with `<< "bar"` you are mutating the same object three times (in the case of array `b`)

To populate an array with separate instances of the same string, do...

```
Array.new(3) { "foo" }
```

Comment: you can use `a[0].equal? a[1]` to determine object identity

Comment: OK so what you're saying is that the second one is (what I would call in C) three pointers to the same string? It's just really odd when the first comparison comes out as `true` and it looks like everything is fine. Thanks.  Something else weird happened to me the other day when i realized that `z=y+y` gave me a new array, but `z=y` gave me two references to the same array. I understand the way round this is to do `z=y.dup`

Comment: Yes, exactly right... three pointers to the same string.  However when you compare two strings `"hello" == "hello"` that will come back as `true` because the string contents are the same, not the objects. As @Stefan pointed out, you can do `a[0].equal?(a[1])` versus `b[0].equal?(b[1])` and see the difference as that compares object ids, not string values.

Comment: Also, note that `z = y.dup` only creates a shallow duplicate of 'y'... which is to say it's two different arrays (different objects) but `z[0]` and `y[0]` are still pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Like SteveTurczyn said, `["foo"]*3` create an array concatenating three times a copie of the same object (`"foo"`).

If you what to aplied some function or do something on the elements of the array. Use the method `map!`

Like:

```
a = ["foo", "foo", "foo"]
 => ["foo", "foo", "foo"]
a.map! { |x| x + "bar" }
 => ["foobar", "foobar", "foobar"]

b = ["foo"]*3
 => ["foo", "foo", "foo"]
b.map! { |x| x + "bar" }
 => ["foobar", "foobar", "foobar"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and in both cases the object ID's of the elements of the `map!`'d arrays were all different. They were also completely different from the object ID's of the original arrays.

Comment: Yes, because the `x + "bar`" is a non-mutating operation.   In your original example you did `b.each{|i| i<<"bar"}` but had you used string `+` concatenation...  `b.each{|i| i = i + "bar"}`... that would've also given you new objects and you wouldn't have the problem.  It's not so much the difference between `each` and `map` as it is the difference between `<<` and `+`